# Ошибка запроса в SqLite

Tags: java, android

```
public Cursor ReaderWithDateBaseLite(Context context,String date) {
    this.dbHelper = new MySQLiteOpenHelper (context);
    db = this.dbHelper.getWritableDatabase ();

    this.c = db.query (dbHelper.tableIncoming, new String[]{"summa","description","nameCoast"},  "date LIKE " +  "%"+date+"%", null, null, null, null, null);
```

Не пойму,в чем причина

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "%": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT summa, description, nameCoast FROM Incoming WHERE date LIKE %3:2018%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"'%"+date+"%'"` - текстовые литералы должны быть заключены в кавычки, а чтобы не париться лучше использовать аргументы (особенно когда в запросе много условий):

```
this.c = db.query(dbHelper.tableIncoming, new String[]{"summa","description","nameCoast"},
                  "date LIKE ?", new String[]{"%"+date+"%"}, null, null, null, null);
```